# SQL, COUNT doesn't work in my mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm using mysql 5.1.

Here is my DB schema

```
office
+--------------+----------------+
| office_id    | office_name    |
+--------------+----------------+

employee
+--------------+-----------------------+------------+
| employee_id  | employee_hierarchy_id | office_id  |
+--------------+-----------------------+------------+

employee_hierarchy
+-----------------------+-------------------------------+
| employee_hierarchy_id | employee_hierarchy_description|
+-----------------------+-------------------------------+
```

I want to count the `number of employees` `group by employee_hierarchy_id` for each `office_id`

Here is my request to list factory_id and employee_hierarchy_id:

```
SELECT office_id, employee_hierarchy_id
FROM office, employee_hierarchy
ORDER BY office_id ASC
```

And if I try to add count, it display only one line:

```
SELECT office_id, employee_hierarchy_id, COUNT(*)
FROM office, employee_hierarchy
ORDER BY office_id ASC
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add `WHERE` consition and `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT office_id, employee_hierarchy_id, COUNT(*)
FROM office, employee_hierarchy
WHERE office.factory_id = employee_hierarchy.factory_id
GROUP BY office_id, employee_hierarchy_id
ORDER BY office_id ASC
```

OR *the recommended* syntax

```
SELECT office_id, employee_hierarchy_id, COUNT(*)
FROM office INNER JOIN employee_hierarchy
        ON office.factory_id = employee_hierarchy.factory_id
GROUP BY office_id, employee_hierarchy_id
ORDER BY office_id ASC
```

**UPDATE 1**

if you want to still show records of office even without employee, use `LEFT JOIN`, otherwise `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.office_name , c.employee_hierarchy_description,
        COUNT(b.office_ID) totalCount
FROM    office a
        LEFT JOIN employee b
            ON a.office_ID = b.office_ID
        LEFT JOIN employee_hierarchy c
            ON b.employee_hierarchy_id = c.employee_hierarchy_id
GROUP BY a.office_name , c.employee_hierarchy_description
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
```

Comment: Hi, employee_hierarchy.factory_id doesn't exist, I've updtaded my db schema, by adding my employee_hierarchy table.

Comment: Unknown column 'b.employee_hierarchy_description' in 'field list'

Comment: sorry it should be `c.employee_hierarchy_description`.

Comment: @Tom-pouce NO, as you can see, table `employee` has column `office_id` on it.

Comment: Yes, my bad, not exactly the same DB schema posted here as mine. ;)
It's work perfectly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I found another way of doing it, try this sub-query

```
SELECT SUM(number_of_employees) as 'number of employee per factory',factory_id
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'number_of_employees',employee.factory_id
FROM factory,employee
WHERE factory.factory_id = employee.factory_id
GROUP BY employee.employee_hierarchy_id
) AS tmptbl 
GROUP BY tmptbl.factory_id
```

Hope this helps!